# php mysql how to get the value inside an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

```
array(1) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["list_length"] => string(2) "10" 
    ["id"] => array(4) {
      [0] => string(1) "1"
      [1]=> string(2) "10" 
      [2]=> string(1) "3"
      [3]=> string(2) "13"
    }
  }
}
```

codeigniter

How can I get the values `1,10,3,13` inside

```
["id"]=> array(4) {
  [0]=> string(1) "1"
  [1]=> string(2) "10"
  [2]=> string(1) "3"
  [3]=> string(2) "13"
}
```

I tried :

```
public function recieve($data){
    //var_dump($data);
    $ids = $data;
    var_dump($ids);
    $this->db->set('recieve', '1');
    $this->db->where('no', $ids);
    $this->db->update('trainee')`
 }
```

Comment: man, this question is as bad as it gets

Comment: why you are using <recieve> method , its not clear, pls specify

Comment: What have you tried so far? The given array has clear keys, so why not use them?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Comment: how to upvoting just my first time here sorry . i already check the answer that helped my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Working demo : https://eval.in/1009067

```
$arr = array(array("list_length" => "10" ,"id" => array("1", "10" , "3" , "13")));
if (! empty($arr[0]['id']))
{
   $data = $arr[0]['id'];
}
print_r($data);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 13
)
```

In your `recieve` method use like this :

```
$arr = array(array("list_length" => "10" ,"id" => array("1", "10" , "3" , "13")));

if (! empty($arr[0]['id']))
{
   $data = $arr[0]['id'];
}

/*pass this $data to your method like this :*/

public function recieve($data)
{
    /*if $data is return the array just like above in question 
      get all ids like this 
      $ids = $data[0]['id'];
    */
    $ids = $data;
    //var_dump($ids);
    $this->db->set('recieve', '1');
    $this->db->where_in('no', $ids);
    $this->db->update('trainee')`
 }
```

Comment: why are you  using <recieve> method , its not clear, pls specify

Comment: recieve is my function where i want to change the status. default value is 0 means not yet recieve then when recieve change to 1

Comment: i cant get the datas "1"10"3" "13"

Comment: see  my updated answer for that, pass all the ids like this

Comment: in query use where_in instead of where as in my anwer

Comment: i have new problem even if the $ids is empty the datas are updated to 1 why is it?